# Few doubts regarding Maven junit tests parallel execution

Tags: maven-3, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I was looking into how to improve overall execution time for JUnit test cases for my project. For the reference here that we are using the followings:

1. Maven 3.3.9
2. Junit 4.12
3. Maven Surefire Plugin 2.18.1

I was going through "Maven Surefire Plugin Parallel Test Execution" official documentation.

Could someone please clarify following doubts w.r.t. Surefire plugin configuration in pom.xml:

1. If `useUnlimitedThreads` attribute is set to true then is it recommended to provide `threadcount` attribute?
2. Based on above, what would happen if useUnlimitedThreads=true and threadcount=4 (for example). Would `threadcount` value still be considered while executing JUnit?
3. If we want to leverage "threadcount" along with useUnlimitedThreads=false then how to decide no. of threads? My perspective is that we should use useUnlimitedThreads=true with no `threadcount` configuration.
4. If we use configuration [useUnlimitedThreads=false and threadCount=4] then how to decide `perCoreThreadCount` boolean flag value? Default value is true. Also, how declaring it to false might impact execution time?
5. What is the significance of `parallelOptimized` attribute? How it might impact execution time?

Comment: thanks for editing it.

Comment: Could someone please help regarding above queries?